# empty tag for null value in Jibx

Tags: java, xml, jibx

I would like to create an empty tag for one of my attribute when its value is null in JIBX. Can some one please help me out? Lets say i have an attribute called

```
private String webId
```

For the above attribute , there is no value coming from DB, so its always null but , its a mandatory tag to be displayed as part of my response , so i want to show an empty tag for this  attribute as `<webId/>`. My mapping in binding  file is

```
 <value name="webId" field="webId" />
```

Please note: i don't want to manually set its value as empty string if its value is null ,like

```
if(webId==null){
   productDetails.setWebId("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the value in your class to an empty string like :

```
private String webId =  new String();
```

So when JiBX does marshal, the XML will have an empty tag for it.

I tested this and it works for me.